# Firefox Build does not work with Selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, build

for my research, I did some source code modifications in firefox and build it myself. In order to automate testing, I opted to use Selenium but unfortunately, my newly built Firefox seem to not support Selenium.

I did the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary("/path/to/firefox/binary")

d = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

d.get("http://www.google.de")
```

The Firefox does open and is responsive (I can enter a website in the search bar). But after a while, the python script crashes with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firefox.py", line 7, in <module>
    d = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 66, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 109, in _wait_until_connectable
    raise WebDriverException("Can't load the profile. Profile "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I did google that error message and most solutions suggested, that I should Update Selenium since it does not support the Firefox version used. Unfortunately, I installed the newest version of selenium (2.44.0) and I even used an older version of firefox (version 33) to rule out that point.

I also made sure that my code modifications are not the reason for this to crash by building a clean, unmodified firefox. Selenium doesn't work with this firefox either.

If I don't specify a firefox binary and let Selenium use the installed Firefox, everything works fine. So my guess is, that something is wrong with the firefox build, which I did exactly as mentioned in the online documentation (e.g. ./mach build).

Has anyone an idea, what my mistake might be? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Some setup information:

- Firefox 33
- Selenium 2.44.0
- Python 3.4 (also tried 2.7, doesn't work either)
- Firefox build with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Is this a sporadic issue or consistent? I'm seeing this as well, but only sometimes (FF34, selenium2.44.0, python2.7, ubuntu12.04). I do find it weird that this is happening to you mid-script. NOTE that the default profile gets saved to the /tmp directory unless you specify a new one, so make sure you don't have any scripts or anything that could be deleting the profile.

Answer (score 38):

Ubuntu 14.04, firefox 36.0, selenium 2.44.0.
The same problem, was solved by:

```
sudo pip install -U selenium
```

Selenium 2.45.0 is OK with FF36.

update: Selenium 2.53+ is compatible with FF45

You can get older FF versions [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)

Comment: This should be the next step : http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-firefox-36-on-linux-systems/  it worked for me, thanks

Comment: After so much frustration this is the only match that worked for me with Mac OS and Python 3.5

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, it saved my day :)

Answer (score 11):

I have spent a long time debugging this and ultimately gave up trying to make incompatible versions of selenium/firefox work. I just don't have the expertise in firefox to go any further. My recommendation is downloading stable versions from https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/ and keep trying combinations of firefox/selenium that work for your environment. For me, this is:

firefox==32.0.3
selenium==2.43.0

I'm referring to the changelog here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG to see which versions are supposedly compatible.

Basically, what is happening is webdriver is polling on its port until it can establish a socket connection.

```
def _wait_until_connectable(self):
    """Blocks until the extension is connectable in the firefox."""
    count = 0
    while not utils.is_connectable(self.profile.port):
        if self.process.poll() is not None:
            # Browser has exited
            raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited "
                  "before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in "
                  "the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.")
        if count == 30:
            self.kill()
            raise WebDriverException("Can't load the profile. Profile "
                  "Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the "
                  "FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.")
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
    return True
```

And then if there is an socket error, keep going. So what you are probably seeing (at least what I am) is the browser hanging for 30 secs.

```
def is_connectable(port):
    """
    Tries to connect to the server at port to see if it is running.

    :Args:
     - port: The port to connect.
    """
    try:
        socket_ = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        socket_.settimeout(1)
        socket_.connect(("127.0.0.1", port))
        socket_.close()
        return True
    except socket.error:
        return False
```

Bleh. Alright, well I finally just decided to store the specific version I want and switch to the compatible selenium version.

```
bin_dir = os.path.join(const.WEBDRIVER_DIR, 'firefox', 'binary', '32.0.3', 'linux-x86_64', 'firefox')
binary = FirefoxBinary(firefox_path=bin_dir)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

I also highly recommend adding a log file to the firefox binary and checking that. Your issue might be unique and any bizarre errors will be logged there:

```
log_dir = os.path.join(const.LOGS_DIR, 'firefox')
    try:
    os.makedirs(directory)
except OSError, e:
    if e.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(directory):
        pass
log_path = os.path.join(log_dir, '{}.log'.format(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat('_'))
log_file = open(log_path, 'w')
binary = FirefoxBinary(firefox_path=bin_dir, log_file=log_file)
```

Comment: Thank you for you time. When debugging this problem, I came to the same point as you. Strange enough, that stable versions of firefox work like a charm. Unfortunately, i can't use stable versions, because I did some code modifications in the firefox code. So i don't get why a stable version is working, but my self-built version not. Nevertheless, thx for your effort!

Answer (score 4):

Spent an hour on this same issue. For Python3 remember to `pip3`, otherwise it will only upgrade selenium on Python2, and you'll be left wondering why it's still not working.

`sudo pip3 install -U selenium`

Answer (score 2):

For El-Capitan, the followings fixed:

`brew install python`

then

`sudo pip install --upgrade selenium`

Answer (score -2):

I suffered the same problem with FF 36.0.

I recommend you update selenium package to latest version with cmd 'pip install -U selenium'.