# How to fix Selenium WebDriverException: "The browser appears to have exited"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I got this exception when I want to use `FireFox webdriver`

> raise WebDriverException "The browser appears to have exited "
>    WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the
>   FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321907/firefox-build-does-not-work-with-selenium) and updated my selenium, but I already have the same problem.

my code :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
time.sleep(5)
driver.get('http://www.example.com')
```

**UPDATE**

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270337/how-to-fix-webdriverexception-the-browser-appears-to-have-exited-before-we-coul)

and now I have this error

```
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory
Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x407a690>> ignored
```

Comment: update selenium and firefox versions

Comment: @LeonBarkan i wrote in my question that i did it

Comment: Oops :) yes you did

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: @LeonBarkan i test with a simple example, i added it

Comment: i didn't see object initialization for WebDriver only reference

Comment: Which firefox version are you using? If you re on latest selenium (2.53), FF version upto 45 should be compatible i believe.

Comment: @MukeshTakhtani my selenium version is 2.53, how can i find the version of FF webdriver?

Comment: @MukeshTakhtani my firefox version is 43

Answer (score 7):

If you're running Selenium on Firefox 47.0, you need to update to Firefox 47.0.1 <s>which is not released in Ubuntu's main repos.. so you have to add this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa</s>

Release notes:
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/47.0.1/releasenotes/

"Selenium WebDriver may cause Firefox to crash at startup"

Once Firefox 48.0 is out, it will include the fix. I think Ubuntu has skipped this update because it affects very few users.

I can confirm the error with FF 47.0 and Selenium 2.53, and I can also confirm that upgrading to FF 47.0.1 fixes the error.

Comment: for my new server setting, I have Firefox 47.0.1 and selenium 2.53.06, but I still got this error. And for my local development with Firefox 47.0.1 and selenium 2.53.05 works. I am now stucked at how to downgrade selenium to 2.53.05, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: The FF version was indeed the problem in my case.  Looks like Ubuntu is now up to FF 48, which works OK.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed by updating firefox 47.0.0 to 47.0.1 manually

Comment: it works with Selenium webdriver Version: 2.53.6 (tested). firefox 47.0.0 is the culprit. 47.0.1 works! thanks @gunesmes

Answer (score 2):

Just for people like me wasting hours with installing several firefox versions to make this working: same message error appears if you are running tests in an environment without display (e.g. SSH to your vagrant box).

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb

#set display number to :99
Xvfb :99 -ac &
export DISPLAY=:99
```

Remember to put this in a .bashrc because it's valid only in the current session shell.

From:

[Is it possible to run selenium (Firefox) web driver without a GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399557/is-it-possible-to-run-selenium-firefox-web-driver-without-a-gui)

Comment: This is not answer of this question

Comment: @parik This is actually an answer to the question as the error message is the same: WebDriverException "The browser appears to have exited " etc. and I've solved with this.

Comment: @BangTheBank BangTheBank In the case of this question  we USE the GUI and your answer have no sense

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with my selenium script. I had to make sure that I was using the proper software versions as described in the selenium installation documentation, namely Pyhton 3.5 and Firefox version 45 (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox). I am using the selenium version 2.9.1 although from reading around 2.53 may work best.

I noticed in the comments you also questioned how you can check the version of your Firefox. To do this you can go open a Firefox browser, click the menu button and click the question mark at the bottom of the pop-out menu, and finally click "About Firefox". The version number should be the second line of text in the pop-up. There may be other ways to do so but this worked for me.

Hopefully this will help you get your script to run.

Comment: as you said, i installed older version of FF, i checked it by firefox -v and i have FF 43, but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Hmm... not quite sure then. I had the error as you did before your edit and after I downloaded the correct versions of the software and reinstalled selenium 2.5 on my FF 45, I ran your script in python 3.5 and it worked as expected. I would say check your versions again but aside from that I am not sure pal. Sorry for your troubles.

Answer (score 0):

1.Install latest Firefox (mine is 50.1.0)

```
apt-get install firefox
```

2- Download latest geckodriver
from [this repo](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

3- unzip the downloaded file

```
tar -xvf geckodriver-v0.13.0-linux64.tar.gz
```

4- `mv ./geckodriver /usr/bin`

5- `ln -s /usr/bin/geckodriver /usr/local/bin/.`